# div in front off margin of another div, floating divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to float 2 divs next to each other and I want the right div to give a margin in relation to it's parent while the left div is shown in front of the margin of the right div.

I have this code below with some labels and input fields. I gave the inputwrapper a margin-left of 220px to align the inputfields vertically but they don't.

So my quetion is how to get these inputfields vertically aligned without using a table?

Thanks in advance

Code snippet:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13pt;
}
.registerwrapper {
    border: 1px black solid;
    height: auto !important;
    width: 600px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.labelwrapper {
   border: 1px red solid;
   float: left;
   display: block;
   z-index: 100;
}
.inputwrapper {
    border: 1px blue solid;
    margin-left: 220px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}
.row {
    border: blueviolet 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px;
    width: auto!important;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;    
}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout_register.css" />
        
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
        
    
        <div class="registerwrapper">
                <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="labelwrapper"><label for="username">Username:</label></div>
                            <div class="inputwrapper"><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" autocomplete="off" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="labelwrapper"><label for="password">Choose a password:</label></div>
                            <div class="inputwrapper"><input type="password" name="password" id="password"  /></div>
                        </div>    
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="labelwrapper"><label for="password_again">Enter your password again:</label></div>
                            <div class="inputwrapper"><input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again"  /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="labelwrapper"><label for="name">Name:</label></div>
                            <div class="inputwrapper"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" autocomplete="off" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="inputwrapper"><input type="submit" value="Register" /></div>
                        </div>             
                </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can also use for example `class ="col-sm-6"` inside `<div class="row">`

Comment: use css table display properties. `display: table-cell` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position: absolute;` for `labelwrapper` class.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13pt;
}
.registerwrapper {
    border: 1px black solid;
    height: auto !important;
    width: 600px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.labelwrapper {
position: absolute;
   border: 1px red solid;
   float: left;
   display: block;
   z-index: 100;
}
.inputwrapper {
    border: 1px blue solid;
    margin-left: 220px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}
.row {
    border: blueviolet 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px;
    width: auto!important;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;    
}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout_register.css" />
        
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
        
    
        <div class="registerwrapper">
                <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="labelwrapper"><label for="username">Username:</label></div>
                            <div class="inputwrapper"><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" autocomplete="off" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="labelwrapper"><label for="password">Choose a password:</label></div>
                            <div class="inputwrapper"><input type="password" name="password" id="password"  /></div>
                        </div>    
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="labelwrapper"><label for="password_again">Enter your password again:</label></div>
                            <div class="inputwrapper"><input type="password" name="password_again" id="password_again"  /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="labelwrapper"><label for="name">Name:</label></div>
                            <div class="inputwrapper"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" autocomplete="off" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="inputwrapper"><input type="submit" value="Register" /></div>
                        </div>             
                </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: well, thank you. Can you also explain how it works what you did?

Comment: Use position: absolute property for labelwrapper class.

Comment: It works because `position: absolute` takes the element out of the document flow. This means that the left margin of the input is not calculated according to the label, but to the left border of the containing div.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the following classes in your css file

```
.labelwrapper {
 border: 1px red solid;
 float: left;

 }

.inputwrapper {
border: 1px blue solid;
float: right;
margin-right:100px;

}
```